# Google App Script - condition to exclude a specifc folder from being deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SIqo.jpg)

I have working script which will trash any file in a specific folder that is more than 3 hours old. I am trying to find a way to exclude a specific Google doc from being deleted within this folder. The Google doc will have a fixed name. I am hoping that a condition could be added to mny current code that will exclude this from being trashed. Here is the code:

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];
  // Old date is 3 hours
var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ANokXFq7tkz1Uk9PVA');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate <"' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
};
```

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Should be formatted correctly now - thanks for highlighting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  let fileIDs = [];
  let xfid = 'excluded folderid'
  let dt = new Date();
  const oldDate = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHour() - 3).valueOf()
  let cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ANokXFq7tkz1Uk9PVA');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate <"' + cutOffDate + '"');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    let fid = file.getId();
    let ps = file.getParents();
    let pids = [];//collect parent ids
    while(ps.hasNext()) {
      let p = ps.next();
      pids.push(p.getId())
    }
    if (!~pids.indexOf(xfid)) {
      Drive.Files.remove(fid)
      Logger.log('ID: ' + fid + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
    }
  }
  return fileIDs;
}
```

You may need to enable Drive API